# After updating to Windows 10 update 1803 there is a broken GUI modal dialog

Tags: windows-10-v1803

After updating to (presumably) version 1803, after login Windows 10 shows a full-screen dialog that seems to be some kind "accept this EULA or else" thing, but it is largely broken: The text is mostly missing, the buttons don't work.

See screenshot below.

Can someone with a properly working copy at least explain what is being accepted there? Is there a way to decline?

[image: screenshot of problem]

I googled and only found one other report about this, [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/8jxfx7/white_screen_after_windows_10_update_1803/).

Comment: I have assume you have tried to reboot your machine?

Comment: It's a prompt asking you to confirm you want to use Cortana.  Hard to tell which prompt.  The "out of the box" experience for 1803, which this prompt is part of, changed significantly with 1803 due to the improved privacy controls.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. I also found a solution: Just click with your mouse in the area of the text you want to accept. After tht click you scroll to the bottom and click on accept. Repeat that for all the questions, after that Windows is normal again.
It is a way to come through, I couldnot find the real problem. When you run the update assistant you will have the same messed up GUI. Things are related but I don't know how.